# How to check if a VPN is installed on a computer

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, vpn, terminal, ping

I have computer 1 and computer 2.

I can't ping 2 from 1.

But I can ping 1 from 2.

I think that a VPN is installed on computer 2.

How to check if this is the case ?

Comment: It's more likely that computer 2 is just running some kind of firewall that prevents a ping.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac a VPN can come in two forms.

The first is as a network interface visible in System Preferences. You can see one at the bottom of the left-hand pane in the screenshot below :-

[image: Networ prefs]

The second type is run as an application. Public VPNs and some corporate VPNs run this way. All of these tend to place an icon in the menu bar to allow for connecting an disconnecting easily. Look for that.

Your problem is much more likely the firewall on computer 2. Go to the Security & Privacy preference pane in System Preferences, click on "Firewall", click on the lock in the bottom left corner and enter your password to allow changes.

[image: Firewall prefs pane]

Now click on "Firewall Options". You will probably find "stealth mode" enabled. Deselect it and click "OK".

[image]

Now do your test again.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the **Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections** to see if there is VPN profile and status is connecting.

For the ping issue, turn off firewall on both of the computers. If it works, it indicates that either or both of outbound rule on 1 and inbound rule on 2 are causing the problem.

Comment: Both computers are Macs, do you know how to check for VPN on a Mac